# Set Object to Nothing before creating a new instance of object?

Tags: ms-access, vba, adodb

In VBA, is it good practice to set an object to Nothing before declaring a new instance of it?

For example:

```
Private Sub SetupConn()

Const Provider As String = "sqloledb"
Const LanDataSource As String = "127.0.0.1"
Const WanDataSource As String = "mail.12345678.biz:12345"

Dim UserName As String
Dim Password As String

UserName = "myusername"
Password = "mypassword"
```

Here is where I wonder if I should close the 
connection or set it to nothing before reopening to a new one.

```
Set mDBconn = New ADODB.Connection

Select Case mConnMethod
Case WAN
    mConnStr = "Provider='" & Provider & ";Data Source=" & WanDataSource _
             & ";User ID=" & UserName & ";Password=" & Password
Case Lan
    mConnStr = "Provider='" & Provider & ";Data Source=" & LanDataSource _
             & ";User ID=" & UserName & ";Password=" & Password
End Select
End Sub
```

The scenario is that a user is on the road, using a mobile data connection, he arrives at the office and wants to go straight to a high speed wifi connection without closing and reopening the program. In this case what I would do is set the connection method to LAN and call this sub with a reset parameter.

Comment: Not sure in VBA, but if you set the variable with a new reference, the old one will be overwritten and caught by the garbage collector since not used any longer.

Comment: That's part of the reason I tagged it  ADODB, I didn't know if there was any harm to be had by setting the object to nothing without closing it.

Comment: Then, better wait for someone who knows better the adodb model. I know the above, but I'm not sure so don't want to spread wrong information around. Take it with care for the moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a need to set Objects to Nothing inside VBA Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517006/is-there-a-need-to-set-objects-to-nothing-inside-vba-functions).

Comment: I guess part of my question is concerning how this relates to closing an ADODB connection.

Comment: I would still be curious what the answer to this question is, but I actually don't need this scenario anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess according to this [Whats the difference between rs.close vs rs = nothing in a RecordSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542449/whats-the-difference-between-rs-close-vs-rs-nothing-in-a-recordset),
It is good to both close AND set nothing. This answers my question.